# How to make query return 0 instead of empty set if there is no result

Tags: mysql, database

How can i make this query to return a row with 0 value if there is no value for each date

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `panel_messages` WHERE `sent_by` = 'root' 
        AND `send_date` IN ("1395-4-25","1395-4-24","1395-4-23","1395-4-22","1395-4-21","1395-4-20","1395-4-19")
        GROUP BY `send_date`
        ORDER BY `send_date` DESC
```

My expected result is 7 rows like this :

```
| row1 |

| row2 |

| row3 |

| row4 |

| row5 |

| row6 |

| row7 |
```

and if there is no result for one of the rows i want it to be 0 which is default value :

```
| 2 |

| 0 |

| 0 |

| 2 |

| 0 |

| 3 |

| 1 |
```

But right now i just get 4 rows because if there is no result my query doesn't return anything  :

```
| 2 |

| 2 |

| 3 |

| 1 |
```

SQL fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a07486/3

Comment: what do you want you want to return null when count(id) is 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
SELECT sent_by ,"1395-4-25" as `SEND DATE`,COUNT(*)  FROM `panel_messages` WHERE `sent_by` = 'root' AND `send_date` = "1395-4-25"
 union 
SELECT sent_by ,"1395-4-24" as `SEND DATE`,COUNT(*) FROM `panel_messages` WHERE `sent_by` = 'root' AND `send_date` = "1395-4-24" 
union
SELECT sent_by ,"1395-4-23" as `SEND DATE`,COUNT(*) FROM `panel_messages` WHERE `sent_by` = 'root' AND `send_date` = "1395-4-23" 
ORDER BY  `SEND DATE` DESC
```

in this case when date is not found the count(*) return 0; but in the first return null add the 4 select statement and it will return 7 rows now it work but it can be better if i found onother solution i'm going back here

Comment: I  still get 4 rows. If there is no result for one of the dates, query returns empty set. For example this query returns empty result but want it to return 0   :                                                                                                         SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `panel_messages` WHERE `sent_by` = 'root' 
    AND `send_date` IN ("1395-4-25")
    GROUP BY `send_date`
    ORDER BY `send_date` DESC

Comment: ahh is see the problem now let me think about it

Comment: did you try it ?!!

Comment: Yeah thank you but i get some errors and i'm trying to fix them.Please check sql fiddle that i've added to my question

Comment: yes in the second query   :     panel_messages`  sorry must be like   `panel_messages`

Comment: if fixed the erreur in the answer in the secode query

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as `SEND DATE` DESC
LIMIT 0, 25' at line 6

Comment: fix the name of the table in the second query   panel_messages`   see that i fo forgeted  the "``" sorry for that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117401/discussion-between-charif-and-a-e).

Comment: remove the "as" from ORDER BY i forget it there sorry

Answer (score 2):

Please give it a try:

```
SELECT 
 COALESCE(YT.total,t.total) AS cnt
FROM 
(SELECT 0 AS total) t
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT 
        COUNT(id) AS total 
    FROM `panel_messages` 
    WHERE `sent_by` = 'root' 
    AND `send_date` IN ("1395-4-25","1395-4-24","1395-4-23","1395-4-22","1395-4-21","1395-4-20","1395-4-19")
    GROUP BY `send_date`
    ORDER BY `send_date` DESC
) YT 
ON 1=1;
```

**Note:**

A dummy row has been created with value `0`.

Later doing a `LEFT JOIN` between this dummy table and your `query`

And finally using `COALESCE` you can achieve the default count `0` if your main query doesn't return anything.

**EDIT:**

*Query:*

```
SELECT 
COALESCE(YT.count,0) AS count
FROM
(
    SELECT ADDDATE('1395-01-01', INTERVAL @i:=@i+1 DAY) AS DAY
    FROM (
    SELECT a.a
    FROM (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS a
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS b
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS c
) a
JOIN (SELECT @i := -1) r1
) dateTable
LEFT JOIN 

(
    SELECT
        send_date,
        COUNT(id) AS count
    FROM
        `panel_messages`
    WHERE
        `sent_by` = 'root'
    AND `send_date` IN (
        "1395-4-25",
        "1395-4-24",
        "1395-4-23",
        "1395-4-20"
    )
    GROUP BY
        `send_date`
    ORDER BY
        `send_date` DESC
) AS YT 
ON dateTable.DAY = YT.send_date
WHERE dateTable.DAY IN ('1395-04-25','1395-04-24','1395-04-23','1395-04-20');
```

In order to get zero count for the dates which don't exist you need to create a temporary table where all the dates (under a certain range) reside.

Then making a left join between the date field of this temporary table and `send_date` field of your table would do the job done almost.

Finally you need to use `COALESCE` to get `0` if the `count` is `NULL`.

<kbd>[**WORKING DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a07486/7/0)</kbd>

Comment: it works but it doesn't return 0 if subquery returns empty set (no result)

Comment: In fact you don't need to use `IFNULL` on `count`. If your result set is empty then you won't get any row. Do you want to show default value when the result set is empty?

Comment: yes thats what i want and i would like to default value be 0

Comment: Then try with `count` only. it returns `0` if your result set is empty

Comment: I used your edited query but it doesn't return 0 or anything if result set is empty.

Comment: What does it return?

Comment: It doesn't return anything

Comment: What's your expected output? Just to return a single row having column `0` when the full result returned by your query is empty?

Comment: In my query for `send_date` i'm using 7 dates so what i want is 7 rows to be returned and if there is no result for each date i want to that row be 0

Comment: it's not that clear. how many rows would you expect when the query returns empty result? 1? Better post your expected output in tabular form in your question.

Comment: Please check the answer now.

Comment: Thank you but not working again. Please check my edited question.

Comment: Share an sql fiddle (with sample data). Actually the question you asked was unclear.

Comment: Now it works but the what @Charif suggested also works but i'm not sure about the performance so i don't know which one is better.Thank you for your help and your time.

Answer (score 1):

onother answer what you are trying to do is impossible without the union :

but you can try some think else 
create a temporary table that contain your date

```
create Table temporary (
         send_date date
   );
  insert INTO temporay("1395-4-25"),("1395-4-24"),("1395-4-23"),("1395-4-22"),("1395-4-21"),("1395-4-20"),("1395-4-19")
```

than do select with rigth join between your table and this one now you will have record for the date that don't have send_by

```
panel_messages.sent_by | panel_messages.send_date | temporary.send_date
root                         "1395-4-25"              "1395-4-25"
root                         "1395-4-25"              "1395-4-25"
null                         null                     "1395-4-24" 
null                         null                     "1395-4-23"
root                         "1395-4-19"              "1395-4-19"
.
.
.
```

now you count how much message in every day all i did is create a result that can return what you need :

Try this select after you create the temporary table

```
SELECT  temporary.send_date, count(sender_by)
from panel_messages RIGTH JOIN temporary ON  (temporary.send_date = panel_messages.send_date)
where 
panel_messages.sent_by like 'root'
group by  temporary.send_date
ORDER BY send_date DESC;
```

Comment: try this solution i did'nt you union here   there no way in mysql to create a table from a list  of value or to create a select from a list of value so we must create a temporary table to insert the value in it than do the join

Comment: tell me if i didn't work because i test it and it work